# Google products and services not loading at all

Tags: firefox, dns, proxy

This started suddenly. Basically i was watching videos on youtube, and suddenly it stopped loading. After a few refresh attempts, it started saying `Firefox cannot find the server at .....` Then I tried to google for solution, but even google won't open. My gmail, google maps, analytics, hangouts, basically anything belonging to google has suddenly stopped working. I am even unable to log in this site with my google account, and I am using proxy to post this question itself cause it says "`This site requires javascript from a different domain which failed to load`" (basically jQuery from the google cdn failed to load). I tried Firefox, chrome, ie, opera and safari all with the same error. All other sites open but none of the google products.

However if I use a proxy, it seems to work. I have tried clearing cache, cookie, offline data, flushing my DNS, and now I have no idea how to get things back to normal. Please tell me if anyone knows of any solutions.

Edit: Ipconfig /all dump->

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Bluemagica>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluemagica-Lapt
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1705 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 64-5A-04-74-7F-F4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad7b:a182:5551:4ef9%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, April 27, 2014 1:35:52 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, April 28, 2014 1:35:55 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 358898180
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-56-07-39-74-86-7A-41-3A-E7

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-86-7A-41-3A-E7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3A63C9DB-C4DE-4D2F-86BE-D946683A7D3B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:47:39d7:c4a2:c0f(Preferr
ed)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::47:39d7:c4a2:c0f%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: Can you describe your network setup? Is this a home Internet conncetion? Are you behind a router? Is there a firewall in your computer or router?

Comment: have you tried turning the computer off and on again? unplugging both the router and the modem, leave them unplugged for 10 seconds and then plugging them back in?

Comment: This is my home connection, yes. I have my modem connected to a wifi-switch and I am using that to access net on my laptop.

Comment: have you checked your firewall?   it is possible that an antivirus application or the firewall is blocking the connection to Google's IP for some reason.  I would make sure that you are not getting re routed somewhere else when you type in the Google addresses

Comment: Could it be that _malware_ is interfering with DNS queries to Google-related domains?

Comment: Restarting didn't work. I have disabled my firewall, but it didn't help, plus I don't understand how a firewall can start hating google suddenly. Now the malware idea is intriguing, but avast didn't find anything either...so if it's a malware, what would be a good tool to check with quickly? But one thing for sure is that, I am not being routed anywhere else, it is simply failing.

Comment: try to go to Google.com and then post the url after it can't find the server or whatever it does.  then we can tell if you have a toolbar that is trying to keep track of you or whatever. my guess is that there is something your http request is going through before it is sent to Google and Google doesn't like it.  have you tried a different computer on the same home network?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of running `ipconfig /all` in a command prompt window (assuming you're using Windows). Please also include any DNS and DHCP settings and values from your router's administration interface. I'd also suggest trying something distinctly non-Google; I often use http://www.sunet.se/ (the Swedish University Network's main web site) for testing since it's pretty much *on* the Swedish backbone; if that fails to load, I *know* something is badly wrong.

Comment: hmm, the url stays at http://www.google.com/ after the failure, but curiously enough, firebug shows the status as `Aborted` after `24.27ms`

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I added the requested info. And sunset.se seemed to open to a red page with a large `P` logo saying `Parkerad hos Loopia`. So I am guessing that is working.

Comment: @aoi_magi It's **sunet, not sunset**. Anyway, you're obviously getting *something*, so *something* is obviously working for you in terms of name resolution; it's not an all-out failure. I'm not sure if that's good or bad, actually. And I'm still not seeing your router's DNS and DHCP data.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am sorry but I am not much into networking and my routers were setup by a hardware engineer, so I am not sure what to get or how. Would it be possible for you to come to chat and guide me a bit?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a pretty odd setup. Your system is on 192.168.0/24, with a default gateway and DHCP server properly within that subnet, but the DNS server your system is pointed at is in a different subnet (192.168.1/24). Usually your system would be pointed at your router for both DHCP and DNS, or you'd get passthrough of your ISP's DNS server details (which probably wouldn't be in RFC 1918 space). Is this a deliberate setup? **Have you tried** setting the DNS and IP settings both to Automatic on the network card in the control panel? Make note of the old settings first!

Comment: You'll need some more rep to use chat, unfortunately. And I don't have a Windows installation handy to compare against.

Comment: Please see if you can join me on this link http://www.chatzy.com/73535980581421